# Consolidate Python versions on MacOS

Tags: python

How can I link or point the "OS" version of Python on MacOSX to the Python installation via installer/PIP?

The issue I have is the following:

When I do "python --version" on terminal, the output is : "Python 3.7.6"

However, when I installed the latest version via the Python Installer, which installed version 3.11, the "python --version" still shows 3.7.6

So if I try to use poetry, it picks up that I only have 3.7.6, but if I run pip install python, it says I have 3.11.

Comment: You can use `python3.11` to launch the python 3.11 version.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't really help - when I use any of my IDE's they only "see" my 3.7.6